# little confused about JOINING 5 tables together

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT p1.id, 
        p2.id, 
        p3.id, 
        p4.id, 
        p5.id 
FROM social_media_mareketing_blog p1 
    INNER JOIN social_engine_mareketing_blog p2 ON p1.id = p2.id 
    INNER JOIN branding p3 ON p2.id = p3.id 
    INNER JOIN strategy p4 ON p3.id = p4.id 
    INNER JOIN mobile_marketing p5 ON p4.id = p5.id 
WHERE p1.id = '1' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Is this query ok for joining 5 tables in MySQL?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be okay?

Comment: Yes, MySQL can join five tables.

Comment: A bit odd to get all id's when they're constrained to all be equal to each other, otherwise no problem.

Comment: What happened when you ran it? Did you get "1,1,1,1,1"?

Answer (score 0):

The query is syntactically correct. Only: You usually wouldn't have the same ID for different tables. In your query you find a record with id 1, then you look for a record in the next table with id 1 and so on. Only to show the ones (and twos etc.) in your results. This doesn't make much sense, I daresay.

Moreover, you would always think first what you want to show. Are you really interested in the combinations of all five tables? Or would you rather want to show rows for which mobile marketing *exists* for example (then you would preferredly use the EXISTS clause instead of a join). Also: Will there always be matching records in the other tables? Otherwise you would have to outer join tables, rather than using inner join for them all.

At last two side remarks: You would usually not limit your results without specifying an order by, but I guess this is just for testing purpose, right? And for readability, you would use meaningful alias names, such as mb for the media blog, and eb for the engine block (or whatever you like; maybe smmb for social_media_mareketing_blog), just not a, b, c, d or p1, p2, p3, p4.

Here is an example for a typical query:

```
SELECT 
  mb.blog_id, 
  mb.id, 
  mb.content,
  eb.id,
  eb.content,
  ...
FROM social_media_mareketing_blog mb
LEFT JOIN social_engine_mareketing_blog eb ON eb.blog_id = mb.blog_id
...
WHERE mb.id = '1'
AND EXISTS
(
  select *
  from mobile_marketing mm
  where mm.marketing_id = mb.marketing_id
);
```